# Regex expression for a given string

Tags: python, regex

I have a small issue i am running into. I need a regular expression that would split a passed string with numbers separately and anything chunk of characters within square brackets separately and regular set of string separately.

for example if I have a strings that resembles

```
s = 2[abc]3[cd]ef
```

i need a list with `lst = ['2','abc','3','cd','ef']`

I have a code so far that has this..

```
import re
s = "2[abc]3[cd]ef"
s_final = ""
res = re.findall("(\d+)\[([^[\]]*)\]", s)
print(res)
```

This is outputting a list of tuples that looks like this.

```
[('2', 'abc'), ('3', 'cd')]
```

I am very new to regular expression and learning.. Sorry if this is an easy one.

Thanks!

Comment: `re.findall(r'\w+', s)`? Or `re.findall(r'\d+|[^\W\d_]+', s)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate fix is  getting rid of the capturing groups and using alternation to match either digits or chars other than square bracket chars:

```py
import re
s = "2[abc]3[cd]ef"
res = re.findall(r"\d+|[^][]+", s)
print(res)
# => ['2', 'abc', '3', 'cd', 'ef']
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9baSKp/1) and the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UohLO1). *Details*:

- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `|` - or
- `[^][]+` - one or more chars other than `[` and `]`

Other solutions that might help are:

```py
re.findall(r'\w+', s)
re.findall(r'\d+|[^\W\d_]+', s)
```

where `\w+` matches one or more letters, digits, underscores and some more connector punctuation with diacritics and `[^\W\d_]+` matches any one or more Unicode letters.

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/DQkrSe).

Comment: re.findall(r'\d+|[^\W\d_]+', s) this particular case works like a charm! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't try a regex that will find all part in the string, but rather a regex that is able to match each block, and `\w` (meaning `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`) feats well

```
s = "2[abc]3[cd]ef"
print(re.findall(r"\w+", s))  # ['2', 'abc', '3', 'cd', 'ef']
```

Or split on brackets

```
print(re.split(r"[\[\]]", s))  # ['2', 'abc', '3', 'cd', 'ef ']
```

Comment: I think like Jonathan is pointing out the string is irregular. If I introduce a string in front of 2, all the solution breaks. for example if my string is s = "sm2[abc]3[cd]ef" the output i get is ['sm2', 'abc', '3', 'cd', 'ef']. Instead it should be ['sm', 2, 'abc', '3', 'cd', 'ef'].

Answer (score 0):

Regex is intended to be used as a *Regular* Expression, your string is *Irregular*.
regex is being mostly used to find a specific pattern in a long text, text validation, extract things from text.

for example, in order to find a phone number in a string, I would use RegEx, but when I want to build a calculator and I need to extract operators/digits I would not, but I would rather want to write a python code to do that.